# Certain RTP Payload Types not reaching destination

Tags: web, browser, webrtc, wireshark, rtp

One of our in-house application uses RTP to stream video and audio from remote office to HO. Recently we're facing an issue where only audio is reaching destination (HO) but not video.

We've 2 lease lines and this issue occurs only when our network traffic is on one particular lease line. We've asked service providers and they've confirmed that they don't block ports/protocal and asked us to check the application.

We've ran Wireshark at both source and destination and found that source (remote office) is sending both PT (96 and 111) while only 1 PT is being received at destination.

Wireshark Log>>>

Captured at source: -[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1cqQ.png)

Captured at destination: -[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iv4j.png)

We're suspecting this issue might be related to browser or video codec.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you have MTU issues?

Comment: We've already allowed MTU 1500, Do we need allow jumbo frame?

Comment: Have you checked that packets over 1400 bytes are able to get through the link?

Comment: Thanks You jch.

We've allowed 1500MTU  not checked, But in case of MTU issue server should send fragmentation request, right? But we're not finding fragmentation request in pcap.

And will ping with high MTU will confirm the MTU issue? or is there any other test method?

Comment: Ping with high MTU should be good enough.

Comment: Thank You, 

No issue found wrt  network. Looks like some browser compatibility issue. Video feed is working fine for in Mozilla Browser.